# Github Actions, set shell via matrix variable

Tags: github-actions

I have a job in Github Actions that uses a matrix. I want to run some of the job steps on a custom shell that depends on a matrix variable.

Specifically, the image has a foreign chroot so I can emulate any hardware architecture and run native binaries for it. The custom shell is just a wrapper script around bash which runs the commands in the chroot and with the emulator for the desired target architecture.

The matrix looks about like this:

```
cross_build:
  strategy:
    matrix:
      job:
      - { release: bullseye  , arch: armhf  , ocaml-version: 4.14.0  , publish: true }
```

I have tried

```
shell: bash-${{ matrix.job.arch }} {0}
```

(`bash-$ARCH` being the wrapper script), but get an error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/CI.yml (Line: mmm, Col: nn): Unrecognized named-value: 'matrix'.
```

If I hardcode the architecture in the shell, everything works:

```
shell: bash-armhf {0}
```

So the issue really is about resolving variables in the `shell` element.

Is there a way to pass a variable in this place so that different instances of the job run on different custom shells?

If not, I would need to have one `bash-wrapper` script and somehow pass it the information about the target platform I would like to use. A command line argument is presumably not an option if I can’t pass variables in `shell` – so what is the standard way of passing that information to the custom shell?

Comment: Like [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdjUEOgjAQRfc9xQ8xYWON657DnTGmYLFoaUlnGjSEu0sRXLiZycz/eS94hSHEZ+PCcL211GuurRCPUJESABvivAHiqNnc398L6DTH9rVdc26NcwpnsntUeptSx842F7HUYvIkwyxMVfKcpNMZL1a86WmjSXjdGYVTjv8Eu3Fc3Yflg2lCOR6n8lecNQqmtgFFBhQfkNtC+Q==)?

Comment: I’ve updated the question to show the matrix. Each row of the matrix has a particular combination of arch, OCaml version and possibly other parameters, so we’d still need to resolve that somehow. As for your example – is that meant as a syntactically correct example?

Comment: btw, according to actionlint playground, my matrix and usage of matrix variables in `shell` passes verification. Github rejects it nonetheless.

Comment: Oh, right. Then, it's better if you added a minimal workflow example in your example. That would be easier to test.

Comment: Looks like it's an **open issue** (https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/444) and `shell` doesn't take custom arguments at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Azeem, variables in `shell` [are currently not supported](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/444).

This works:

In the workflow definition, add the following to the job:

```
env:
  CROSS_ARCH: ${{ matrix.job.arch }}
```

Then, for the custom shell, specify the path to the wrapper script – one single script regardless of target architecture, thus no use of variable in `shell`.

In the wrapper script, evaluate `CROSS_ARCH` and choose the emulator and chroot based on that.

Since I already had multiple copies of a single script, which would determine the architecture by the name with which it was invoked, this was very easy to implement and is even cleaner than converting `/bin/bash-ARCH` into `ARCH` by stripping the beginning.